# how can I find intersection of multiple lines with a curve?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a file which has x and y. For each line that passes from the y-axis, I can find the intersection but I wanted to have an automatic way to find the intersections of a bunch lines that pass from y-axis like the figure below:

*perspective result*
[image]

the code that I have written for finding intersections one-by-one is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open('txtfile1.out', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
xx = []
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    if (y[i] > 0 and y[i-1] < 0) or (y[i] < 0 and y[i-1] > 0):
        xx.append((x[i]+x[i-1])/2)

yx = [0 for _ in range(len(xx))]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(xx,yx, color="C2", marker="o", ls="", ms=10)
```

the thing that I have

*Current result*
[image]

Comment: Both figures are the same

Comment: @TimStack yes, but in one of them, I need to have the intersection of the solid line with multiple straight dashed lines while I could write the code for obtaining intersections one by one.

Comment: @TimStack now you can see the differences, you were right in terms of uploaded pictures

Comment: Do you know the y-values of the straight line? Are they always the same? Are they stored inside another file? A second for-loop inside the already existing one could be a solution.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle the y-values which are the straight dashed lines can be defined arbitrarily based on my case. but I have thought this way to define them  `divider = np.arange(min(y),max(y),100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set up an extra loop to check for multiple intersection values which you input and use dictionary to hold list of matches against intersection value as key. This theoretically should plot all intersections of y you desire into same graph

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open('txtfile1.out', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
intersections = [0, -20, 10]
intersection_matches = {intersection: [] for intersection in intersections}
# or just define directly: intersection_matches ={ 0: [] , -20: [], 10: [] }
for i in range(1, len(x)):
  for intersection, xx in intersection_matches.items():
    if (y[i] > intersection and y[i-1] < intersection or (y[i] < intersection and y[i-1] > intersection)):
       xx.append((x[i]+x[i-1])/2)

plt.plot(x,y)
for intersection, xx in intersection_matches.items():
    yx = [intersection] * len(xx)
    plt.plot(xx, yx, color="C2", marker="o", ls="", ms=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open('txtfile1.out', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
xx = []
treshold = #what ever you want
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    if (y[i] > treshold and y[i-1] < treshold) or (y[i] < treshold and y[i-1] > treshold):
        xx.append((x[i]+x[i-1])/2)

yx = [treshold for _ in range(len(xx))]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(xx,yx, color="C2", marker="o", ls="", ms=10)
```

the y= treshold is where you want to watch the intersection